# Abstract of question shows inexistant ampersand prior to ellipsis

Tags: bug, design

The following text of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099194/swi-prolog-abs-operator-not-working-in-clpfd-module)

```
abs(X-Y) #>= 2, X #>= Y, ...
```

is incorrectly abbreviated to

```
abs(X-Y) #>= 2, X #&...
                   ^
```

as seen [with this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clpfd): [image: incorrect rendering]

It should rather abbreviate to `X #...` or `X #>...`

Comment: It is cutting off the encoded text before the text is decoded instead of after. The `>` symbol is encoded as `&gt;`